# Как обратиться к элементу формы из класса в Qt?

Tags: qt, классы, qgridlayout

Здравствуйте.
Пишу сапёра. Мне нужно из класса `My_PushButton` обратиться к `gridLayout_2` (*просто поместил на форму, динамически не создавался*), в котором расположены элементы класса `My_PushButton`, чтобы, если при помощи ЛКМ нажмут на "мину"(мина - значение 9 в переменной `val` у `My_PushButton`), деактивировать `gridLayout_2`, тем самым закончить игру.
Попробовал следующее:

1. ```
   QWidget *form = QApplication::activeWindow();
   ```

   ```
   form->blockSignals(true);
   ```

   или

   ```
   form->setDisabled(true);
   ```

   В таком случае блокируется окно, а вместе с ней и кнопка `pushButton`, которая нужна для рестарта при поражении.
2. ```
   Ui::MainWindow *ui;
   ```

   ```
   ui->gridLayout_2->setEnabled(false);
   ```

При таком подходе получаю ошибку "Segmentation Fault", хотя указатель не пустой по идее.

Класс My_PushButton:

```
    class My_PushButton: public QPushButton{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    //QWidget *form = QApplication::activeWindow();     //A pointer to the active window (widget) in order to further access form elements through it
    int val;                                            //A variable that will store either the number of mines in the neighborhood, or the mine itself
    My_PushButton(int val = 0): QPushButton(), val(val){
        setFixedHeight(25);
        setFixedWidth(25);
        setIconSize(QSize(25, 24));
        setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(146, 36, 255)");
    }
private slots:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
        if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton){
            this->setIcon(QIcon(R"(C:\Qt\pictures/flag.png)"));

        }
        else{
            if(val == 0) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(234, 223, 246)"), this->setIcon(QIcon());
            if(val == 1) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("1");
            if(val == 2) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("2");
            if(val == 3) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("3");
            if(val == 4) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("4");
            if(val == 5) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("5");
            if(val == 6) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("6");
            if(val == 7) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("7");
            if(val == 8) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("8");
            if(val == 9){
                this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon(R"(C:\Qt\pictures/bomb.png)"));
                //form->blockSignals(true);
                //form->setDisabled(true);
                //ui->gridLayout_2->setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
signals:
    void rightClicked();
    void leftClicked();
protected:
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event){
        if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton){
            emit rightClicked();
        }
        else{
            emit leftClicked();
        }
    }
};
```

Весь файл mainwindow.cpp, где содержится `My_PushButton`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVariant>
#include <time.h>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QObject>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

class My_PushButton: public QPushButton{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    //QWidget *form = QApplication::activeWindow();     //A pointer to the active window (widget) in order to further access form elements through it
    int val;                                            //A variable that will store either the number of mines in the neighborhood, or the mine itself
    My_PushButton(int val = 0): QPushButton(), val(val){
        setFixedHeight(25);
        setFixedWidth(25);
        setIconSize(QSize(25, 24));
        setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(146, 36, 255)");
    }
private slots:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
        if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton){
            this->setIcon(QIcon(R"(C:\Qt\pictures/flag.png)"));

        }
        else{
            if(val == 0) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(234, 223, 246)"), this->setIcon(QIcon());
            if(val == 1) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("1");
            if(val == 2) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("2");
            if(val == 3) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("3");
            if(val == 4) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("4");
            if(val == 5) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("5");
            if(val == 6) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("6");
            if(val == 7) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("7");
            if(val == 8) this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon()), this->setText("8");
            if(val == 9){
                this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(209, 173, 245)"), this->setIcon(QIcon(R"(C:\Qt\pictures/bomb.png)"));
                //form->blockSignals(true);
                //form->setDisabled(true);
                //ui->gridLayout_2->setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
signals:
    void rightClicked();
    void leftClicked();
protected:
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event){
        if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton){
            emit rightClicked();
        }
        else{
            emit leftClicked();
        }
    }
};

#include "mainwindow.moc"

void MainWindow::on_action_triggered()
{
    QTextBrowser *tb = new QTextBrowser(); //Create a window with game rules
    tb->setFixedSize(610, 150);
    tb->setText("Use the left click button on the mouse to select a space on the grid.\n"
                "If you hit a bomb, you lose.\n"
                "The numbers on the board represent how many bombs are adjacent to a square.\n"
                "For example, if a square has a \"3\" on it, then there are 3 bombs next to that square.\n"
                "The bombs could be above, below, right and (or) left, or diagonal to the square.\n"
                "Avoid all the bombs and expose all the empty spaces to win Minesweeper.\n"
                "You can right click a square with the mouse to place a flag where you think a bomb is. This allows you to avoid that spot.");
    tb->setEnabled(true);
    tb->setVisible(true);
}

My_PushButton** my_rand(int size){

    /*************************************************************
     * The following values ​​will be used to customize the cells: *
     * 0 - empty cell;                                           *
     * 1 - cell showing the number of mines around it = 1;       *
     * 2 - cell showing the number of mines around it = 2;       *
     * 3 - cell showing the number of mines around it = 3;       *
     * 4 - cell showing the number of mines around it = 4;       *
     * 5 - cell showing the number of mines around it = 5;       *
     * 6 - cell,showing the number of mines around it = 6;       *
     * 7 - cell showing the number of mines around it = 7;       *
     * 8 - cell showing the number of mines around it = 8;       *
     * 9 - mine cell;                                            *
     *************************************************************/


    srand(time(NULL));
    int counter = 0, numines = (rand() % ((size * size) / 2)) + 1, x = 0, y = 0; //numines - number of mines, x & y - coordinates for placing a mine

    My_PushButton **but;            //Create a 2D array and fill it with 0
    but = new My_PushButton*[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        but[i] = new My_PushButton[size];
    }

    while(numines > 0){ //Placing mines
        x = rand() % size, y = rand() % size;
        if(but[x][y].val != 9){
            but[x][y].val = 9;
            numines --;
        }
    }

    //Checking neighbors for mines
    for(int i = 1; i < size - 1; ++i){                  //Checking an area without borders
        for(int j = 1; j < size - 1; ++j){
            if(but[i][j].val != 9){
                if(but[i - 1][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                if(but[i - 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                if(but[i - 1][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;

                if(but[i][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                if(but[i][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;

                if(but[i + 1][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                if(but[i + 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                if(but[i + 1][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
            }

            if(counter > 0) but[i][j].val = counter;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {                   //upper border
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
                if (but[i][j].val != 9) {
                    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                        if (but[i][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i + 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i + 1][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (counter > 0) but[i][j].val = counter, counter = 0;
                    }
                    if (i == 0 && j == size - 1) {
                        if (but[i][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i + 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i + 1][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (counter > 0) but[i][j].val = counter, counter = 0;
                    }
                    if (i == 0 && (j > 0 && j < size - 1)) {
                        if (but[i][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i + 1][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i + 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i + 1][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (counter > 0) but[i][j].val = counter, counter = 0;
                    }



                    if (i == size - 1 && j == 0) {                  //lower border
                        if (but[i - 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i - 1][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (counter > 0) but[i][j].val = counter, counter = 0;
                    }
                    if (i == size - 1 && j == size - 1) {
                        if (but[i - 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i - 1][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (counter > 0) but[i][j].val = counter, counter = 0;
                    }
                    if (i == size - 1 && (j > 0 && j < size - 1)) {
                        if (but[i][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i - 1][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i - 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i - 1][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (counter > 0) but[i][j].val = counter, counter = 0;
                    }



                    if (j == 0 && (i > 0 && i < size - 1)) {        //left border
                        if (but[i - 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i - 1][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i + 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i + 1][j + 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (counter > 0) but[i][j].val = counter, counter = 0;
                    }



                    if (j == size - 1 && (i > 0 && i < size - 1)) { //right border
                        if (but[i - 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i - 1][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i + 1][j - 1].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (but[i + 1][j].val == 9) ++counter;
                        if (counter > 0) but[i][j].val = counter, counter = 0;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    return but;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_pressed()
{
    QVariant index_but = ui->comboBox->currentIndex(); //Find out the value selected in the ComboBox
    int a = index_but.toInt();

    switch(a){
    case 0:             //number of buttons = 10
    {
        My_PushButton** but =  my_rand(10);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
                ui->gridLayout_2->addWidget(&but[i][j], i, j);
            }
        }
        ui->gridLayout_2->setSpacing(0);
        ui->gridLayout_2->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);

        /*for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
            delete [] but[i];
        }
        delete but;*/

        break;
    }

    case 1: //number of buttons = 17
        break;

    case 2: //number of buttons = 25
        break;

    case 3: //self-entry
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Файл mainwindow.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>650</width>
    <height>800</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>649</width>
    <height>770</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1000</width>
    <height>1000</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Minesweeper</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="horizontalLayoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>157</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
       <property name="editable">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="currentText">
        <string>Level 1</string>
       </property>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Level 1</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Level 2</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Level 3</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Self-entry</string>
        </property>
       </item>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Start</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="gridLayoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>601</width>
      <height>541</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2"/>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="enabled">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>650</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuMinesweeper">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>Menu</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="action"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="actionNotes"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuMinesweeper"/>
  </widget>
  <action name="action">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Rules of the game</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionNotes">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Notes</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С вашим классом эксперименты ставить не стал. Сдается что для деактивации вам надо не компоновщик трогать, а виджет:

```
 // sender() - My_PushButton, sender()->parent() -  gridLayoutWidget
((QWidget*)sender()->parent())->setEnabled(false)
```

А вообще не совсем понятно зачем весь огород со своим классом.
Просто приведу пример:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
// ........
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton(QString("?").arg(i),this);
        btn->setProperty("my_data",i);
        ui->gridLayout_2->addWidget(btn,1,i);
        btn->installEventFilter(this);
    }
}
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *sender, QEvent *event)
{

    if(event->type()!=QEvent::MouseButtonPress&&event->type()!=QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
        return false;

    int val=-1;
    if(!sender->property("my_data").isValid())
        return false;
    val = sender->property("my_data").toInt();
    if(event->type()==QEvent::MouseButtonRelease){
        if(((QMouseEvent*)event)->button()==Qt::LeftButton){
            if(val==9) ((QWidget*)sender->parent())->setEnabled(false);
            else ((QPushButton*)sender)->setText(QString("%1").arg(val));
        }
        if(((QMouseEvent*)event)->button()==Qt::RightButton){
            ((QPushButton*)sender)->setText(QString("X").arg(val));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Добрый вечер.
Это именно то, что нужно, но в силу дальнейших препятствий мне пришлось взять глобальный указатель на форму и через него проводить необходимые манипуляции с объектами. Да, понимаю, что данный подход не очень желателен, но для себя(обучения) сойдёт. 
Спасибо большое за помощь.